# Ввожу Hello world! Вывод: 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, Как убрать запятую с пробелом после 33?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
certain_line = input()

deliter = ', '

for i in range(len(certain_line)):
    if i == certain_line[-1]:
        deliter = ''

    print(ord(certain_line[i]), end=deliter)
```

Comment: Не знаю как на питоне выводить строки, выведите после вашего вывода 2 символа `\b\b`

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
certain_line = input()


deliter = ', '
answer = []
for i in range(len(certain_line)):
    answer.append(ord(certain_line[i]))
print(*answer, sep=deliter)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

а такой код устроит?

```
certain_line = input()

print(', '.join(map(str, map(ord, certain_line))))
```

ну или вариант 2:

```
print(*map(str, map(ord, certain_line)), sep=', ')
```

или так:

```
print(', '.join(str(ord(i)) for i in certain_line))
```

или так:

```
print(*map(str, map(ord, certain_line)), sep=', ')
```

или так:

```
print(*[ord(i) for i in certain_line], sep=', ')
```

без извратов с `map`:

```
certain_line = input()

res = [ord(i) for i in certain_line]

print(*res, sep=', ')
```

без извратов с циклами:

```
certain_line = input()

res = []

for i in certain_line:
    res.append(ord(i))

print(*res, sep=', ')
```

не очень понял

```
if i == certain_line[-1]:
        deliter = ''
```

вы строку с числом сравниваете - эта проверка никогда не должна работать вроде как

если вам последний символ как разделитель нужен, то код будет таким:

```
certain_line = input()

print(certain_line[-1].join(map(str, map(ord, certain_line[:-1]))))
```

Comment: Я еще не изучил таких методов, if i == certain_line[-1]:
        deliter = '' Когда i будет на последнем символе. Как это написать?

Comment: вам последний символ как разделитель нужен? Если да, то я добавил код в ответ

Comment: Чтобы после 33 не было запятой

Comment: тогда см. первый вариант ответа, запятой с пробелом не будет

Comment: а можно написать без методов, пожалуйста?

Comment: добавил - смотрите, на любой вкус и цвет

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

```
certain_line = input()
for i in range(len(certain_line)-1): print(str(ord(certain_line[i]))+', ', end='')
print(str(ord(certain_line[-1])))
```

***Простое решение в 3 строки. Без особо сложных функций.***

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

здесь можно использовать срез

```
certain_line = input()
deliter = ', '
for i in range(len(certain_line)-1):
    print(str(ord(certain_line[i])) + deliter, end='')
print((ord(certain_line[-1:])))
```